# Remember user in Ionic Firebase app

Tags: android, angularjs, authentication, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm writing an Ionic app using Firebase as the back end and am struggling trying to keep users logged in.
I've tested on Android only at the moment.

When the app launches, I log the user in with `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword`.

After logging in, if the user presses the physical back button a couple of times to close the app, then they launch the app again, they have to log in again because the app has lost their credentials (`firebase.auth().currentUser` is null).

I'd like the app to remember the user on the device when they have logged in, and only log them out if they specifically hit the app logout button.

Here's the code in my app.js

```
angular.module('starter', [
    'ionic',
    'firebase',
    'starter.loginController',
    'starter.resetemailController',
    'starter.signupController',
    'starter.dashboardController',
    'starter.sidebarController'
])

.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $state, CONFIG) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
            // for form inputs)
            // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
            // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
            // a much nicer keyboard experience.
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });

    // on stateChange event if state requires authentication and user not logged in, go to login state
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        if (toState.authRequired && !user) {
            $state.go("login");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    // initialise firebase
    firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxx',
        authDomain: 'xxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com',
        databaseURL: 'https://xxxxxx.firebaseio.com',
        storageBucket: 'xxxxxxxxxx.appspot.com',
        messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    });

})

.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$ionicConfigProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {

    $ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle('center');

    $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'shared/sidebar/sidebarView.html',
        controller: 'sidebarController'
    })

    .state('app.dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: "components/dashboard/dashboardView.html",
                controller: "dashboardController"
            }
        },
        authRequired: true
    })

    .state('login', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: "components/login/loginView.html",
        controller: "loginController"
    })

    .state('signup', {
        url: '/signup',
        templateUrl: "components/signup/signupView.html",
        controller: "signupController"
    })

    .state('reset', {
        url: '/reset',
        templateUrl: "components/resetemail/resetemailView.html",
        controller: "resetemailController"
    })

    // this is a workaround to prevent the $stateChangeStart firing multiple times
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector) {
        var $state = $injector.get('$state');
        $state.go('app.dashboard');
    });

}])
```

When the user logs in, the `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise` makes the app go to the dashboard as the initial state.

The following code re-routes to the login state if the user is null

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (toState.authRequired && !user) {
        $state.go("login");
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

This all works great, but once the user closes the app, I want the app to remember the user so next time they launch, they will go straight to the dashboard state rather than having to log in each time.

I don't store anything at the moment when a user logs in - do I need to store some credentials in local storage or something?

I've read about JWT but I don't fully understand how to create or use them.

I've seen some posts mention `firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken(true)` but again, I don't know what to do with it - do I need to store this token somewhere after login?

Sorry if this is all a bit vague; I'm really new to this and much of it is over my head at the moment.